# How to find the element in kendo data binding function

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, kendo-ui, disabled-input

On the application I am working on I need to disable an element under one of two different circumstances, one if the logged in user only has read only access to the form, two if the conditional logic set up on the field is met. These forms are being generated dynamically, built on the admin panel with drag and drop fields.

The issue I am having is when the conditional logic case has been met but the form is not read only. In the case I am trying now it's to disable some of the fields if the form is being reopened (already saved).

The input looks like this:

```
<input name="userName" id="userName" maxlength="64" type="text" class="k-textbox custom-disable" data-bind="value: formData.userName, disabled: isFormDisabled">
```

The conditional logic sets the disabled property on the input, as well as adding the custom-disable class for CSS. isFormDisabled is a boolean property of the viewModel.

What I would like to do is create a function like this:

```
ViewModel = kendo.observable({    
    ...,
    isFormDisabled: false,
    isElementDisabled: function (e) {
        var customDisabled = $(e.target).hasClass( "custom-disable" );
        return this.get("isEventDisabled")||customDisabled;
    },
    ...
});
```

and change the binding of disabled to this new function, but since the disabled is not an event, when I log e it's undefined - how can I find the element being bound to this iteration of the callback?

[Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IfuWOS/2)

Comment: your `e` param in the function `isElementDisabled` looks like it is part of an event(because you try to read `e.target`) how is binded to your page that function? when is suposed to be called?

Comment: `data-bind="value: formData.userName, disabled: isElementDisabled"`

The caller is the disabled binding of the element, the problem being that when it gets into the function, e is undefined, which is what I need help with, I need to somehow find the element using this callback, e.target may not be the right way, but it was the example I know for what I want, even though it currently does not work.

Comment: `e` shouldn't be undefined in that case, do you have a jsfiddle/dojo with your code for to see where the error comes from?

Comment: [Here it is in a dojo.](http://dojo.telerik.com/IfuWOS/2) This should at least give you a better idea of how this is all built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up figuring out - for the function:

```
isElementDisabled: function (eID) {
    var me = this;
    var element = $("#" + eID);
    var customDisabled = $(element).hasClass("custom-disable");
    return me.get("isEventDisabled") || customDisabled;
},
```

and the binding -

```
<input name="#: columnName #" id="#: columnName #"
    data-bind='value: #: dataContainer #.#: columnName #, disabled: isElementDisabled("#: columnName #")'
/>
```

Since the ID of the element matches the column name and is unique, I can find it by passing that ID into the bound function as a property.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Kendo has its own way for to enable/disable elements, for example, [this explains how to enable/disable a Kendo Combobox](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#methods-enable)

Comment: Yes, and when dealing with MVVM objects you use `data-bind = "disabled: {observable property or function}"` Which I am using, that part is correct, the issue is it is overwriting the disabled property on the element as already set.

Comment: This [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@petyosi/iqEdI) shows it being used the way I want, except my fields on the form don't come from a kendo data source like these do.

Comment: Thats not a kendo data source is a kendo observable, and is binded to the whole document, have you tried that too?

Comment: I should have been more clear,my inputs are not created by a source binding in a template, but the function and property are on the observable. I have updated the question to be more clear in that